# Taxonomy for Single line of text

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, xml, pnp

I'm building a FAQ Accordion with SharePoint lists and I have the previous metadata working with TaxonomyFieldType but how do I target a single line of text?

Column title: FAQKeywords ( Single line of text )
Input: O365Training ( Target? )

```
var viewXml = {
ViewXml: "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>" +
    "<Query>" +
    "<OrderBy>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='SortOrder' />" +
    "</OrderBy>" +
     "<Where>" +

            "<Contains>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='FAQKeywords' />" + 
                "<Value Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>O365Training</Value>" +
            "</Contains>" +

    "</Where>" +
    "</Query>" +
    "</View>"
```

}

Any help would be highly appreciated! Been tackling this all evening.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean here. Are you simply trying to perform a CAML query against a single line of text? What do you mean by "Taxonomy for single line of text"?